# Shortcut to a certain activity in notification dropdown?

Tags: notifications

So the question is simple: I'm looking for a way to create a shortcut in notification dropdown that, when tapped, leads me to a set activity of an app. The activity in question is "Running Services" from Settings, if that matters.

Additional requirements:

- The notification has to be permanent in order to prevent it from
  being cleared.
- The notification has to be of lowest priority to not make it
  interfere with normal notifications (i.e. always display below them).
- Optional - GUI for choosing the activity I intend to start.
- Optional - customizable notification text and icon.

Back in Android 5.x and lower, this (excluding the optional requirements) can be realized with the combination of [Bar Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coinsoft.android.barshortcuts) and [NotificationManager (Xposed)](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ghostflying.nfmxposed), the former grants access to the activity I want, while the latter sets its priority. However, in Android 6.0+, the default App Management interface has been modified, and the previous activity no longer points to "Running Services" which is now hidden in Developer Options.

Bar Shortcut is a very old app and I can't expect it to be updated to match the changes. Other apps that create notification shortcuts focus on the basic toggles or an app in general (not its activities).

Note that I am aware that apps like Nova Launcher and More Shortcuts allow you to generate shortcuts to activities on your homescreen, however I don't want any icon to clutter up the homescreen, nor do I want to change my current launcher.

Thanks in advance for any useful answers.